# why am I getting an empty test suite with parallel_tests ruby gem

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake, parallel-testing

Any help getting the gem working would be appreciated.  I'm down to configuration issues (i think) and there isn't a lot of documentation to help me get running.

So I have the parallel_tests gem in my project.  I believe I have two problems, one that cannot be seen without the other.

The first problem is that I don't think I have my database.yml file setup correctly.  #1 we call it servers.yml (not sure if there is an importance with the name), and 2 we didn't have a "test" section setup.  The example shows

```
test:
  database: yourproject_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
```

our server.yml file contains the following:

```
db1:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  url: url_to_db1
  username: uname
  password: pass

db2:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  url: url_to_db2
  username: uname
  password: pass

db3:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  url: url_to_db3
  username: uname
  password: pass
```

so I just added the test line above the rest of the databases at the top of the file

The problem is I cannot even check to see if that's working right because when I try to run the parallel_tests gems, it returns empty!!!!

This is the guide I've been following, with the exception of finding out I had to require parallel_tests/tasks into my rakefile: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

I have `require 'parallel_tests/tasks'` in my rakefile

I run the 3 commands in the parallel_tests gem to get execution running (don't worry about the java options and java tool options)

[image]

As you can see, there are no error messages, nothing out of the ordenary other then my tests do not run with or without the parameters to the features task.  The following is a printout of the trace stack

[image]

Comment: update, refactored name to database.yml - no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, the newer versions of the gem allow you to run on any platform, with a new command.  parallel_cucumber is the new command.  Check https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests for more details

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your implementation for Oracle, particularly how the new test databases were created?

Answer (score 1):

Was running this on a windows machine... Windows doesn't support forking which is what this gem does.